How to Create a Customer or Supplier Using the Twinfield API (SOAP)
Hey Is there anyone who can guide me...actually I would like to know how to create a customer or supplier using the Twinfield API. Could you please guide me on the following:

What API endpoint or URL should I use for creating a customer or supplier in Twinfield?

What XML structure should I use in the request body to create a customer or supplier?

Are there any specific parameters (such as company ID, customer/supplier code, etc.) I need to include in the request?

What type of response should I expect after creating a customer or supplier?


Reference: Twinfield API doc
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your help!
I’m trying to create a new customer in the Twinfield API using Python and SOAP. I’ve constructed the request XML and included the necessary headers. However, I’m receiving the following error:
**
Error Message:**
Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid SOAP action.

Constructed the request XML for creating a customer.
Used the Authorization header with the access token provided by the Twinfield login.
Sent the request to the endpoint

https://api.accounting.twinfield.com/webservices/processxml.asmx?wsdl.

# Construct request XML
customer_xml = f"""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:twin="http://www.twinfield.com/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <twin:Header>
            <twin:AccessToken>{access_token}</twin:AccessToken>
            <twin:CompanyCode>{company_code}</twin:CompanyCode>
        </twin:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <twin:CreateCustomer>
            <twin:Customer>
                <twin:CustomerCode>{customer_code}</twin:CustomerCode>
                <twin:Name>{customer_name}</twin:Name>
                <twin:Address>{customer_address}</twin:Address>
                <twin:ZipCode>{customer_zip}</twin:ZipCode>
                <twin:City>{customer_city}</twin:City>
                <twin:Country>{customer_country}</twin:Country>
                <twin:VatNumber>{customer_vat_number}</twin:VatNumber>
            </twin:Customer>
        </twin:CreateCustomer>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""

# Send the request
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'SOAPAction': ''  # (This might be where I'm missing something.)
}
response = requests.post(f'{cluster}/webservices/processxml.asmx?wsdl', headers=headers, data=customer_xml)

I expected the API to process the request and create a new customer in the Twinfield system, returning a 200 status code along with a success message or some data in the response.
